# Eclipse: "The import java.io cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have several Android projects in Eclipse, and all is fine, except one (a library) that can not resolve any imports.

The java.io imports do resolve fine in other Android projects in the same workspace, and previously (I haven't used it for over a year) this library worked fine, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the compiler compliance for the library project

Comment: Should it read `import java.io.*;` ?

Comment: Just restarting Eclipse helped me! :P

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Check two things

**Eclipse preferences**

1. Check your Eclipse preferences: `Java` -> `Installed JREs`
2. The one that you're using should be marked and it should be a JDK not just a JRE.

**Project build path**

1. Also check your project's build path: Right click on the project -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path`
2. Check in the `libraries` folder whether the JRE System Library is present and ...
3. If not add it using `Add library` -> `JRE System Library` and then
   select the correct one (from an installed JDK).

Comment: Thanks. That solved part of the problem - no idea why I have to add it, as other projects in the same workspace don't have it explicitly added and still work. Next problem is now the Google API which is explicitly present in other projects, not here, and I have some resolve problems there too.

Comment: OK that part solved too: Add Library; Android Classpath Container; select itself; OK. Bizarre.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was went mad in searching for this answer.

Comment: Also, it worked for me only after restarting the eclipse. So try that too after trying this if it doesn't work instantly. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 9):

I am using Maven an this is what I did to re-solve -->

1. Right click on project
2. Maven -> Update Project. Make sure you choose 'Force update of Snapshots/Releases'.
3. Also check the 'clean project', 'update project conf from pom' and 'refresh workspace resource options' and click ok.

Comment: The *Force update of Snapshots/Releases* was what I was missing ... took ages to do update though!

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

- Close the project and reopen it.

OR

- Clean the project ( = rebuilds the buildpath and thereby reconfigures the JDK libraries).

Comment: I am working on a complex open source project with multiple maven modules and closing and reopening them all  worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the JRE Systems Library in my Project Tree.
And navigating to Projects' Build Path and 'Add(ing) Library' worked!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem with Eclipse 2022-6 and java-17-openjdk-amd64. I just appeared during editing in another file, the same code had worked before.

For me, all settings were correct and none of the above tricks worked. What I then did was completely removing the import command `import java.io.Closeable;`, saving the file, adding the same import command back at the same place, and saving again. The error disappeared.